# Is there a way to re-assign an R accessor function and use it to update the variable properties it accesses?

Tags: r, function, functional-programming, variable-assignment, accessor

In my code there is a situation where I conditionally want to use one accessor function or another throughout the code.  Instead of having an if-else statement for every time I want to pick which accessor to use and coding it explicitly, I tried to conditionally assign either of the accessor functions to a new function called `accessor_fun` and use it throughout the code, but this returns an error when I use the accessor function to reassign the values it accesses.  Here is a simplified example of the problem I am having:

```
#reassigning the base r function names to a new function name
alt_names_fun <- names

example_list <- list(cat = 7, dog = 8, fish = 33)
other_example_list <- list(table = 44, chair = 101, desk = 35)


#works
alt_names_fun(example_list)

#throws error
alt_names_fun(example_list) <- alt_names_fun(other_example_list)

#still throws error
access_and_assign <- function(x, y, accessor) {
  accessor(x) <- accessor(y)
}
access_and_assign(x = example_list, y = other_example_list, accessor = alt_names_fun)

#still throws error
alt_names_fun_2 <- function(x){names(x)}
alt_names_fun_2(example_list) <- alt_names_fun_2(other_example_list)


#works
names(example_list) <- names(other_example_list)
```

As you see if you try the code above, an example of the kind of error I am getting is

```
Error in alt_names_fun(example_list) <- alt_names_fun(other_example_list) : 
 could not find function "alt_names_fun<-"
```

So my question is, is there a way to do the reassignment of R accessor functions and use them in a way like I am trying to in the example above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Accessor functions are really pairs of functions. One for retrieval and one for assignment. If you want to replicate that, you need to replicate both parts

```
alt_names_fun <- names
`alt_names_fun<-` <- `names<-`
```

The assignment versions have `<-` in their name. This is a special naming convection that R uses to find them. Since these are character normally not allowed in basic symbol names, you need to use the back ticks to enclose the function names.